# Java Part of ASSIGNMENT i cant do

Tags: java, function, methods

list() method

```
// return a string that contains all the HotelRoom objects in the HotelRoom array.   

public String list()   
{ 

}
```

•   The list method will return a string containing all the rooms that the user entered into the system. If there are no rooms entered this method lets the user know that no cars exist.

•   This method is public, returns a String value and takes no parameters.

•   Firstly check that the array is not empty by using the following code:

```
if(myHotelIn.isEmpty())
{
System.out.println(“All rooms are available”);
}

else

{
```

In this method the second thing you need to do is to declare a local String variable, called list. This will hold the list of all rooms in the array and will be returned from this method.

•   If the HotelRoom array is not empty (hint: use the isEmpty() method),

o   write a for loop that will retrieve each room in the array and add its details (room name, room type and room price) to the list variable.
        Return the list variable.

```
}
```

HEY I HAVE A PROBLEM WITH THIS PART OF JAVA APPLICATION. I HAVE GOT ASSIGNMENT TO DO BUT I AM REALLY STUCK WITH IT, I'VE DONE MOST OF THE WORK BUT THIS ONE GIVE ME A LOT OF TROUBLES. I DON'T KNOW EVEN WHERE TO START. PLEASE IF YOU CAN GIVE ME SOME TIPS WITH IT. THANKS

Comment: Do you really expect anyone to read through all that and help you ? Be specific. Show what you have tried. What part dont you understand etc.

Comment: @Remik B, this question will likely get put on hold. Have a look through the FAQ on how to ask questions here - using the tips there will improve your chances of getting a good answer and solving your problem. Two things in particular: 1. format your code properly and 2. DON'T SHOUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should be looking into is a `for each loop`. This is a type of loop that goes through every single element in an array or `Collection` implementation. You can read up on these [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Next, you'll need to look into the `StringBuilder` class, which can be read about [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). This class is designed to allow efficient creation of a `String` object, which you will be using.

Finally, you'll need to use the `append` method in the `StringBuilder` class, to link up several `String` representations of each `HotelRoom`, probably using the `toString()` method.

***NOTE***

You'll notice I've not provided any code, because I don't think you've had a fair go at solving the issue just yet. Edit in your attempts and I'll edit in some code.